# @keyframes animation background-position not working

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

I am trying to create an animation background in a small div, but chrome is getting me unknown property name for the @keyframes all time, and I have the gradient, but I am unable to sho the animation.

```
  @keyframes gradient {
    0% {background-position: 0%}
    100% {background-position: 100%}
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes gradient {
    0% {background-position: 0%}
    100% {background-position: 100% }
  }
  .labelSincroAlert {
 text-align: center !important;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,#F17C58, #E94584, #24AADB , #27DBB1,#FFDC18, #FF3706);
 background-size: 600% 100%;
 animation: gradient 16s ease infinite;
 -webkit-animation: gradient 16s ease infinite;
 animation-direction: alternate;

 }
```

I'm using cuba framework and scss for this, It's important?

[Here in the inspector is where I get the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPtvW.png)

This only happends to me because I am doing an extension from the cuba-platform hellium theme. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: _“but chrome is getting me unknown property name for the @keyframes all time”_ - no idea what that is supposed to mean here. If you are getting error messages, please quote them verbatim (instead of giving us your own paraphrased version); if you mean something else, please explain properly.

Comment: I am not getting an error in the console, is just in the style inspector.

Comment: I don’t know where you would get this, not able to reproduce this with the code you have shown.

Comment: As you say this is you can't reproduce this with regular html and css, It works perfectly. It's looks like is something related with being an extension from the cuba-platform theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I was using helium-ext.scss, and in this cases you have to use helium-ext-defaults.scss. It was inded related with cuba-framerwork and his theme. To solve it just put you @keyframe inside of helium-ext-defaults.scss and the rest of the code on helium-ext.scss.